# How to automatic detect mistakes when you try to destructurize an array into object?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Some times one mistype `{}` instead of `[]` causes unexpacted errors and hard to debug. For example this code will not trigger errors and will compile:

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
}

interface State {
  items: Item[];
}

const state: State = {
  items: [],
};

const newItems: Item[] = [{ id: "123" }, { id: "234" }];

console.log(Array.isArray(state.items)); // true

// WTF??? no error
state.items = {
  ...state.items,
  ...newItems,
}

console.log(Array.isArray(state.items)); // false

// error, it is ok
state.items = {
  0: {id: "val"},
};
```

But in runtime, you will get an objects, instead of array, with keys `{0: ..., 1: ... }`

Comment: Interesting, never seen anything like this before, I don't know what the answer is here.

Comment: @bugs javascript array is just an object. Typescript just check object signature, but in this case, signatures is same `[key: string]: value`.

Comment: Maybe this can be a solution https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring ?

Comment: @Jboucly it is different

Comment: This will cause problems because although the array items are still there by index, other properties (e.g. `.length`, `.push(...)`) are not there. This seems like a bug in Typescript; check the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) to see if there is an issue about it, and if not, consider creating one yourself.

Comment: The static compiler fails with mutations and this is one of the reasons to avoid mutations.

Comment: @kaya3 I didn't found some related issues, but may be I am not asking correctly. I will keep searching some time, if nothing will be found, I will post an bug report.